# Sheepit Problem

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine

Sheep it saying:
"Your project has been blocked because 'Your project has been detected as too heavy, to protect the render farm, the project has been blocked. Since it could be a false negative, you can redeem it by rendering ONE frame of it. If the render time is appropriate, it will be automatically unblocked'.
Members can not render your project BUT you still can."

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Although you have an answer here, your question is actually off-topic as it is about an external service and nothing to do with Blender itself.

Comment: You can do what the message said and render one frame. If you can render it in an acceptable time compared to your hardware, your project will be unblocked. Otherwise, optimize your scene and try again. Personally, I would advise you just optimize anyway. Faster scenes mean faster render for you and sheepit, and hence less points to spend on that render, and more for future renders.

Answer (score 3):

Your render is too heavy to be rendered by lower spec computers connected to SheepIt. You can either render it yourself, or optimize the scene.

If optimizing the scene isn't enough for SheepIt, you have no choice but to render it yourself and wait. You can try looking into render farm software for Blender and connect multiple computers at your home if you have them so you can speed up the rendering.

Based on my experience SheepIt is quite strict when it comes to how heavy your scene is. Most times I've had to render the scenes myself and end up regretting having my PC used by SheepIt and getting nothing back.

Comment: In my personal experience with Sheepit and looking at how many projects they get done, they let a lot of absurd projects pass for **free** service. A fair amount of the people I've seen their projects rejected for being too heavy or time-consuming to render, their projects were poorly made (not saying it is your case). Many projects I've looked in this situation used duplicated data to no end, ridiculous amounts of ridiculously large textures, subdivisions, particles, samples, ... No matter how you render, time is money, you should pay attention.